# C insert newline issue (homework)

Tags: c, jvm-bytecode

I'm writing a Java bytecode program using Jasmin and Yacc, and I want to use fprintf function to write "ldc \"%s\n\"\n" into a .j file, but the resulting file would always lack the newline. For example:

```
    fprintf (fp,"ldc \"%s \\n\"\n",$6.val.get_char);
```

would be represented like this in the .j file:

```
    ldc "Hello" (no newline character \n added)
```

("Hello" is the corresponding string obtained from $6.val.get_char)
How can I fix this issue?  Thanks!

Edit: I've found out the issue, so the problem is solved now. Many thanks to @Rohan Bari for the help!

Edit 2: The solution turns out to be exactly the same thing I did earlier, so the following code:

```
     fprintf (fp,"ldc \"%s\\n\"\n",$6.val.get_char);
```

is already correct, the problem is simply located elsewhere. Still, Thanks for everyone who helped!

Comment: That is not Java code.  The `fprintf` function is C.  Please fix the tags.

Comment: @Stephen C Tag fixed, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You might be better off [just writing the resulting bytecode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html) instead of going the Jasmin detour.

Comment: You might provide the solution you found as an answer.

Comment: Read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book